# Edit hosts file on Kindle Fire

Tags: adb, amazon-kindle-fire

I'm trying to edit the hosts file on a Kindle Fire.

I should say that I'm not interested in rooting the device (unless I have to) and am not trying to hide adverts or prevent software updates etc. I just use the device for web development and use hosts to route made up domains to a server.

I've pulled the hosts file using ADB, but I can't push it back as I'm unable to mount it with write permissions.

Is there a simple method for me to push the file using ADB without having to go through the whole process of rooting? Any simple way to get write access?

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer:

No.

### Explanation:

This action would involve multiple steps:

- re-mount `/system` read-write
- write the `hosts` file to `/system/etc/hosts`
- re-mount `/system` read-only

Each of the step requires root permissions, as the file belongs to `system:system` and usually is read-only to other "users".

Comment: OK. I thought that might be the case, I shall have to about rooting. Seems like a lot of hassle for something (that should be) so simple!

Comment: That's called security. If it would be easy to circumvent, a malicious app could use that to re-direct you to fraudulent sites (e.g. having enter you credit card information and other sensitive data so they can collect them, while you think you've just entered them on a "safe place").

Comment: True. But once I've enabled ADB I know I've stripped away a level of security

Comment: But that's something the *user* can control (and an *app* cannot -- I never saw an app that can plug in a USB cable, and the *USB Debugging* setting should also be impossible to "switch" by an app). -- If you want to *discuss* security, please don't do so here (we are not a forum), but rather in chat (as soon as you have the required rep of 20) or check e.g. at the XDA developers forum. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot edit the host file without root privileges.

But, if you have access to the internet connection on which your kindle in connecting, you can modify DNS entries there. Your kindle first looks at its host file, then asks the DNS server to resolve a hostname. Provided you have admin privileges somewhere in the chain, you can insert your own record; Since you don't have admin access on the localhost (Kindle), you go further up the chain to a link where you do have admin rights.

If you are going over Cell Data or are on a wifi network that you don't own, you could instead set up a VPN to a network to which you do have full rights. Then set up whatever DNS records you want (in the hosts file of the VPN server, or some other method). When connected to a VPN, your device should query the DNS server over VPN, thus giving you control once more.